# Celery: A chain within a group - partial signatures fail

Tags: python, celery

Here is a very simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@shared_task
def sub(x, y):
    return x - y

@shared_task
def mult(x, y):
    return x * y

c = group(
    chain(
        add.s(4), mult.s(2)
    ),
    sub.s(1)
)(3)
```

This is supposed to give me the result `[14, 2]` but instead I am getting the following error message:

> TypeError: add() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

So it seems as if something is wrong with the partial signatures and that the initial `3` is not passed on to the functions in my chain. What is the problem here and is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any added arguments(`3`) will be prepended to the args in the signatures(`task.s`) only. They won't be propagated to primitives(like chain, group, chord).

If you know added arguments before hand, you can do

```
c = group(
    chain(
        add.s(4, 3), mult.s(2)
    ),
    sub.s(1)
)(3)
```

Otherwise, you have to redesign your work-flow.

Comment: I see. Well, thank you. Then I really have to redesign the work-flow :(